# Can't externally access my home server on one phone

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, nas

I've got a NAS server running with nginx, which I can successfully access from different devices and networks.

However, I cannot access the server with my main phone (using 4G). I don't get a response when I ping the domain either. It's not an issue with mobile devices, as I've had my friends test and successfully load the site the NAS is hosting.

If I use a VPN, I can access it on my phone - so maybe it's a DNS issue? Any help would be much appreciated.